# Are there any problems with using the same identifer for both a function expression and the var I assign the function expression to?

Tags: javascript, function, expression, identifier

For example:

```
var foo = function foo() {};
```

So far I haven't encountered any problems, but I wonder why I don't see this more often after learning that named function expressions are preferred over anonymous function expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's absolutely fine. Note that it's nearly identical to

```
function foo() {
}
```

The only difference (but it's a significant one!) is that my example (a function *declaration*) is *hoisted* and yours (a named function expression) is not. That also means mine can't appear within a flow-control structure (such a block connected to an `if` or loop) and yours can. Other than that, they do the same things:

- Create an identifier `foo` in the current scope that refers to the function
- Create a function with a *name* (which is also `foo`); that name is in-scope within the function

Without your `var foo =`, a named function expression does the latter but not the former.

---

On some obsolete JavaScript engines, named function expressions were handled incorrectly, but anything vaguely modern (so, not IE8) works correctly.